# how to call AWS step function from front-end javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I defined an AWS step function defined like this in my serverless.yml file.

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: create.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes
          method: post
          cors: true
          #authorizer: aws_iam
 findMatchingAlerts:
    handler: findMatchingAlerts.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: findMatchingAlerts
          method: post
          cors: true
          #authorizer: aws_iam
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
      name: CreateNewListingAndSendNotificationStateMachine
      events:
        - http:
            path: CreateNewListing
            method: post
        - http:
            path: FindMatchingAlerts
            method: post
      definition:
        Comment: "Step function for inserting a new listing, looking up user alert filter, and sending out email notifications"
        StartAt: CreateNewListing
        States:
          CreateNewListing:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-create"
            Next: FindMatchingAlerts
          FindMatchingAlerts:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-findMatchingAlerts"
            End: true
```

Both `CreateNewListing` and `FindMatchingAlerts` are 2 lambda functions.

Here is what I want to do: I have a front end UI with a button that calls the step function when pressed, and pass appropriate inputs to the step function for processing, and I currently have something like this:

```
 return API.post("notes", "/CreateNewListing", {
      body: input
    });
```

However, I am able to execute the step function from AWS console. But when trying to hook up my front end button with the step function, I am getting is `Error: network error` when ever the button is pressed, so I am guessing the call to the step function is incorrect.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.You will have to create an IAM Role for API Gateway
2.Attach a policy to the IAM role
3.Create your API Gateway API - > Create Post/Get Method -> 
    choose Integration type : Aws Service
    choose AWS Region
    AWS Service : Step Functions
    HTTP method : POSt
    Action : StartExecution
    Execution role : Provide Role
and set other parameters.

4.Deploy the API Gateway API

5. Test the Communication between API Gateway and Step Functions
   On the /execution - POST - Method Execution page, choose Test.

On the /execution - POST - Method Test page, copy the following request parameters into the Request Body section using the ARN of an existing state machine (or create a new state machine), and then choose Test.

```
{
   "input": "{}",
   "name": "MyExecution",
   "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:HelloWorld"
}
```

refrence

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your front end application to write a record to DynamoDB. Then you would need to add a [Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) on that DynamoDB table (it will watch for new record entries). Once triggered, the Lambda function would prepare an execution input from the DynamoDB record and [execute the step function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-invoke-sfn.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, CORS does not work when using API Gateway with Step Functions. I had to create an intermediary Lambda function to call the API Gateway.